# Create a remote kill switch for an iOS app

Tags: ios

I want to be able to remotely prevent an app from opening that is installed on another device.
The reason behind this is that I do remote freelance work and when I send demo applications to clients I want to know that if they stop communicating or run off without paying I can disable to app so they cannot use it anymore.

Comment: Hiding something from Apple? That's a no-no.

Comment: You really should get it touch with apple about this. If someone else tries to take ownership that would be copyright infringement (unless you have signed that over). You should also talk to paypal about it (and possibly link to this question).

Comment: My question has been marked as 'unclear'. Although it was a bit long-winded, I explained fully what the situation was and what I needed. That was until Mike W came and edited the question.

Comment: I was originally going to write something along the lines of "Sorry it's a bit long winded, but I thought I'd best explain myself rather than just come on and say 'I want a kill switch'". My OP explained what had happened to me and asked how to prevent it from happening again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will follow @J2theC's advice. In case anyone is curious on how to do it a more maliciously, I got this to run on launch

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/test.txt"];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

if ([string isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    exit(1);
}
```

That works. But that's just a bit of fun. Like I said, I will use @J2TheC's approach.

## =**Edit**=

I have come back to this code and completed it to an acceptable level.
        Check this out:

So all the checks take place in the AppDelegate, asynchronously. Hopefully @Taum will agree with this.

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
{
    int trialOK;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[self trialCheck:@"http://yourwebsite.com/appID.txt" completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSString *string){
    if (succeeded) {

        if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSLog(@"Trial test connected - all is ok!");
            trialOK = 1;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:trialOK forKey:@"TRIAL"];

        }else{

            NSLog(@"Text file found. It is telling me to quit. Remembering this until dev says otherwise.");

            // Will now show an alert with the contents of your .txt file before closing. Something like "Your trial has
            // expired. Please contact the dev to resume usability of this app. This app will now close" would be appropriate

            [self showAlert:string];
            trialOK = 2;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:trialOK forKey:@"TRIAL"]; //Saves to device that app is not allowed to open
        }
    }
    else{

        // If no connection to .txt file, app checks if it is already banned

        NSInteger trialInt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"TRIAL"];
        NSLog(@"failed online check. Trial int is: %d (0 = quit. 1 = ok)",trialInt);

        if (trialInt == 2) {
            [self showAlert:@"Your trial has expired. Disconnecting from the internet won't help. Please contact the dev to resume usability of this app. This app will now close"];
        }
    }
}];

return YES;
}

-(void)showAlert:(NSString *)alertString{

   UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Trial Expired" message:alertString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
   [alert show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    exit(1);
}

- (void)trialCheck:(NSString *)urlString completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, NSString *string))completionBlock
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if ( !error )
                               {
                                   NSString *tString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                   completionBlock(YES,tString);
                               } else{
                                   completionBlock(NO,nil);
                               }
                           }];
}
```

As you can see, this code checks against a .txt file on a server. As long as that .txt file is completely empty, everything will operate fine.
If an internet connection is unavailable then your app won't crash and still run.

If you add anything to your text file then the next time your app is launched it will show an alert with the body of your .txt file then quit the app once the UIAlertView is dismissed. The fact that you have done this is now saved to the device so it will remember that you have banned the app from opening.

If the user then disconnects from the internet and the app is unable to connect to the .txt file it will then check if you have previously banned the app. If this is true it will, again, show an alert and then quit the app.

Once you empty the .txt file again it will re-enable the app again, restoring functionality.

Remember to remove this code before handing the complete work over, unless you want the assurance that you can close it down if the client reverses your payment to try and rip you off.

FYI - I now use websites for freelancing where disputes can be raised, but this is a 'just-in-case' and not a ransom tool.

Comment: `NSString stringWithContentsOfURL` aka synchronously loading files from a remote server is a terrible practice and a big no-no in my book. Please at least use a background queue for this...

Comment: I usually would, but this was just a quick test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for - despite the negative comments - posting such a detailed follow-up. I just implemented it and it's perfect

Comment: you're welcome @user2875404 this saved me on more than one occasion while freelancing online. People think they can rip you off and waste hours of your life without repercussions. Sad times. People on here got defensive over the fact that I wanted to take preventative measures in the future or thought i was just malicious. Not sure. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There are some thing you can do by simply making an API call to a remote server and validating the application, but to be honest there are other, better steps you can take in order to avoid getting yourself into these situations. The first thing is that you should avoid sending the code over until the contractual obligations are met. you can distribute the application using the xcode archives. This will allow them to sign with their own certificates without having the actual code. The second thing is that you can keep all conversations recorded in order to use that in court (or with paypal, since they are abroad). Also, don't be afraid to use freelance website contacts. They will allow you to perform disputes and work with you. Trying to resolve the issues in code will let you vulnerable because they will be able to change the code anyways.

Comment: Thank you for a helpful answer. I'm new to contract work. Can you recommend anywhere that would be a good place to advertise?